# Salesforce : Enable free API Total Usage EventLogFile

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

While working on Salesforce I got an email like below

You are receiving this email because you’re an admin of an org where the use of legacy API versions was detected. Versions 21.0 through 30.0 of the Salesforce Platform SOAP, Bulk, and REST APIs are deprecated and unsupported; you must remediate unsupported calls before these versions are retired and unavailable.

To identify applications using unsupported APIs that will be retired, contact the developers of applications you use in your org to determine what API versions are being used or review API events with the free API Total Usage EventLogFile.

I need to review my APIs to find the deprecated ones. I tried to enable API Total Usage EventLogFile, but not found better documentation on it. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to follow steps from https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=000354473&type=1

It says there's a free event log you can fetch, even if you don't pay for whole Event Monitoring package.

> *NEW* in Summer ’21 - Free “ApiTotalUsage” Event Type

Where exactly are you stuck? Query returns 0 results?

```soql
SELECT LogFile, EventType, CreatedDate 
FROM EventLogFile 
WHERE EventType IN ('API', 'RestApi', 'ApiTotalUsage')
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

Logs are kept for 1 week.
For each result you're then supposed to download the file (Postman? SoapUI? Workbench? Anything that can run REST API commands, [Workbench's rest explorer](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php?startUrl=%2FrestExplorer.php) is easiest because it handles the passing session id for you), get the CSV and filter through it in MS Excel or what have you